# Automatically selecting a checkbox in datagridview when another checkbox is selected

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

A little help would be much appreciated, I am designing a bike hire/booking program as an extension to a current project in VB using a MS Sql DB.

I have a datagridview that is showing several rows of data which is pulled in from my DB, and I am manually adding two more columns in order to have a couple of check box columns.

The idea is that if someone selects a bike using the first check box column, then the second check box column (for selecting a helmet) will automatically be selected.  If the person doesn't want a helmet, then the user can deselect that option.  This is so that the user will automatically be given a helmet unless they make the decision not to have one, instead of having to opt in for a helmet.

How do I make the selection of the first check box enable the second check box?  I have an event handler for when the user clicks on the cell:

```
 Private Sub dgvBikeAvailability_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvBikeAvailability.CellContentClick
    drBikeAvailability = dvBikeAvailability(e.RowIndex).Row 

    'MsgBox to test data pass through
    MsgBox(drBikeAvailability("bikeName")) 

End Sub
```

I have been trying to access the extra columns I have added to the datagridview, but because they are not present in the datatable, I am unable to do so in the even handler.

Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there anything in the database that relates Bike to Helmet?  Or is it just some hand-made rules?

Comment: Why not just make this checkbox checked by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the fist checkbox is at column index 0 and the second is at index 2
(I think you can replace the indexes with the names of the columns).
You need to handle the value of the checkbox yourself, as the event seems to disable to normal behavior of the click.

```
Private Sub dgvBikeAvailability_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvBikeAvailability.CellContentClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = Not dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
        dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = dgvBikeAvailability.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Let me know if it worked.